# Query optimization using index on range query

Tags: sql, sqlite

My table with two columns and an index :

```
CREATE TABLE T (a integer primary key, b integer not null);
CREATE INDEX Ti on T (b, a);
```

Column `a` is primary key (unique), column `b` can have duplicates. The query :

```
SELECT * from T where b=5 and a>3 order by b, a limit 1;
```

One binary search should be enough to locate the smallest (b, a) pair that meets the condition if it makes full use of the index. Moreover, [the document on SQLite query planner](https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html) specifically states :

> the index might be used if the initial columns of the index (columns a, b, and so forth) appear in WHERE clause terms. The initial columns of the index must be used with the = or IN or IS NULL operators. ***The right-most column that is used can employ inequalities.*** For the right-most column of an index that is used, there can be up to two inequalities that must sandwich the allowed values of the column between two extremes.

But `explain` and `explain query plan` is quite disappointing (SQLite 3.8.8.3) :

```
sqlite> explain query plan select * from T where b=5 and a>3 order by b,a limit 1;
0     0              0     SEARCH TABLE T USING COVERING INDEX Ti (b=?)

sqlite> explain select * from T where b=5 and a>3 order by b,a limit 1;
5     SeekGE         2     14    2     1              00               
6       IdxGT          2     14    2     1              00               
7       IdxRowid       2     3     0                    00               
8       Le             4     13    3                    54               
9       Copy           3     5     0                    00               
10      Column         2     0     6                    00               
11      ResultRow      5     2     0                    00               
12      IfZero         1     14    -1                   00               
13    Next           2     6     0                    00
```

It's using the index only for locating the first row with `b=5` and then linear scan to find rows with `a>3`. Instead of SeekGE with `p4=1`, SeekGT with `p4=2` and IdxGT with `p4=1` could directly locate the right row in only one binary search.

Anything I'm missing to make it work better? `ANALYZE` is not an option because this is about a generally better way to handle the range query, not only on specific data set.